# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_37 to have shape (57, 57, 16) but got array with shape (120, 120, 3)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

my training variable shape is (264, 120, 120, 3)
trying to give numpy array of images as input

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2,input_shape=(image_height,image_width,channels)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

below is the error message

```
________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param 
=================================================================
conv2d_36 (Conv2D)           (None, 59, 59, 8)         224       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_37 (Conv2D)           (None, 57, 57, 16)        1168      
=================================================================


Total params: 1,392
Trainable params: 1,392
Non-trainable params: 0
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_37 to have shape (57, 57, 16) but got array with shape (120, 120, 3)
```

Comment: The error message and your code/summary do not match, its complaining about conv2d_31, but there is no such layer in the summary (only conv2d_32 and conv2d_33). The shapes of the model output and the error message do not match either.

Comment: it is being incremented each time I run it

Comment: Sure, but that does not explain different output shapes between the error and the model.

Comment: Have updated the snippet now

Comment: where is `dense` layer ? You are compeiling without dense ? please refer some sample https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py

Comment: But I am getting the error in the first layer itself right ?

Comment: `conv2d_31` implies you're in a notebook and might want to `from keras.backend import clear_session` and use that function prior to building the model. Graph collisions do happen. Not saying this is the source of your problem, but help yourself by doing this, unless there's some known reason you'd not want to.

Answer (score 0):

This error was because of mismatch in shape between model output and training data.

Please refer sample code in below

```
#Import Dependencies  
import keras 
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense

# Model Building
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['mse'])

# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((100, 28, 28, 1))
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 10))

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2342 - mse: 0.4195
Epoch 2/5
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 234us/step - loss: 1.2183 - mse: 0.4167
Epoch 3/5
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 222us/step - loss: 1.2104 - mse: 0.4151
Epoch 4/5
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 255us/step - loss: 1.2019 - mse: 0.4131
Epoch 5/5
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 239us/step - loss: 1.1938 - mse: 0.4120
```